# How do I use C# to prevent textblocks from overlapping?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I'm trying to use C# to add a TextBlock to my MainWindow at the end of every iteration of a loop.

However, each iteration they're added one on top of the previous one(s). What property of TextBlocks, if any, allows me to keep them from overlapping?

The following is inside a for-loop:

```
TextBlock result = new TextBlock();

result.Text = [string];

result.Width = 200;
result.Height = 100;
result.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);

result.Name = "email" + [string];

Analysis_Space.Children.Add(result);
```

Analysis_Space refers to the main grid of my MainWindow.

Comment: Don't use `Margin` to position controls, use proper *layouting*. Put controls into suitable [container](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/). E.g. you have now `Grid`, [setup](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/) its columns and rows and put children there.

Comment: Use a StackPanel with Veritcal Orientation if you are using Margin to align properly

Comment: Besides using an appropriate Panel (instead of Grid), you should not create or manipulate UI elements in code behind. Better use an ItemsControl and bind its ItemsSource property to an `ObservableCollection<string>`. See the [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) article for all the details. Note also that Panels can be nested. No need to add elements to the top-level Panel.

Comment: All very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @Clemens, your advice is particularly relevant to what I'm learning right now, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct use of panel control will help you resolve this. Which panel to use is up to you depending on your GUI needs. Refer [this](https://wpftutorial.net/Layout.html) link.

For example, put new `StackPanel` on `Analysis_Space`. Then, add your text area to `StackPanel`.

Your new code will look something like below:

```
TextBlock result = new TextBlock();
result.Text = [string];
result.Width = 200;
result.Height = 100;
result.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);
result.Name = "email" + [string];
stackPanel.Children.Add(result);
```

In above code, `stackPanel` represents instance of `StackPanel` which is placed on main grid panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a grid, but you are not telling the program in which row/column it should place your textblock, it will place them in the default 0,0 position (i.e. Grid.Row = 0 and Grid.Column = 0)

You must do this:

```
Grid.SetRow(result, 1);
```

to set your result in the row number 1. You can do the same for the columns